# Is there a way to search a zip file inside another zip file for a string?

Tags: powershell, zip, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am trying to figure out the best way to search for a string value, such as:

```
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -Path $ScriptPath -Recurse | Select-String -pattern $Pattern | Select-Object -Unique path) {$file.path}
```

However, I need to be able to do same search on a zip file, than do it on a zip file inside that first zip file.

Do you have an answer for me?

Thanks,

UnderDog

Comment: Surely you would have to uncompress it first to ensure you string is present somewhere in the archive.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this for read content of zip without extract

```
 [io.compression.zipfile]::OpenRead("C:\temp\20160712-0730.zip").Entries.Name
```